# What is the difference between using std::random_device with pRNG e.g. std::mt19937 and without?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, prng

In C++11 one can generate numbers with the use of `std::random_device` with or without a pseudo random number generator like mt19937.

What will be the difference using this in this exemplar code:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1, 10);

    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        std::cout << dist(rd) << "\t" << dist(mt) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::random_device` is supposed to get you a seed for engines like `mt19937`. The quality of successive numbers produced is completely undefined and may easily be insufficient for practical purposes (such as cryptography), so relying on that is out of question.

Apart from that, `mt19937` will give you the same sequence when given the same seed. A `random_device`s values can be only influenced by the string given to its constructor... which implies implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences that I know of:

1. Using `mt199937` will be faster but less cryptographically secure.
2. `std::random_device` will always be random, but if you initialize your `mt19937` with a constant seed it will always give you the same random numbers:

   `std::mt19937 mt(2014);`

Will give the same sequence of random bits every time. This can be useful if you want to test a specific behavior over and over again. The standard requires this in 26.5.5/4:

> *Required behavior*: The 10000th consecutive invocation of a default-constructed object of type `mt19937` shall produce the value 4123659995.

There is no such equivalent consistency with `std::random_device`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yeah technically only for default-construction, but that's not at all a requirement for `random_device` and that's the only thing I see for the prng...

Comment: and does only mention one value. weird. (note: you meant `mt19937`).

Comment: I mean - there's no requirement on what the `n`th value of `random_device` is. Whereas, given a seed, there is a specific sequence of values that `mt19937` will give you. Even though that's apparently not in the standard.

Comment: If you have a suggestion for how to phrase my answer better, I'm all for it :)

Comment: @Barry, what do you mean by "std::random_device will always be random"? Is it guaranteed to use external source of randomness, like heat dissipation/mouse clicks/movement etc? AFAIK, the standard does not guarantee "true" randomness even for "std::random_device". In case the system has ability for true rng, it will use it, but otherwise no, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @vsoftco You are correct. The standard states (26.5.6/1-2): A `random_device` uniform random number generator produces non-deterministic random numbers. If implementation limitations prevent generating non-deterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine."

Comment: @Barry, thanks, that's what I remembered, and this is a serious issue in crypto programs, as getting true randomness is a very very tricky issue

Comment: I think that by "less cryptographically secure" you mean "not cryptographically secure".